# JavaScript for loop not working?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I haven't really used loops before and I can't seem to figure out why my code isn't working. Was hoping for someone to help point me in the right direction.

```
return firebase.database().ref('Users/' + uid + "/PDR").once('value').then(function display(dataSnapshot) {

  //Number of times the loop should run returning a value
  var number = dataSnapshot.val().Total;

  var i;
  for (i = 1; i < number; i++) {

    //Each time loop runs changes Firebase reference by "1" 
    return firebase.database().ref('/Users/' + uid + "/PDR/" + i).once('value').then(function display(dataSnapshot) {

      var num = dataSnapshot.val().number;
      var dateFrom = dataSnapshot.val().dateFrom;
      var dateTo = dataSnapshot.val().dateTo;
      var dbActivity = dataSnapshot.val().activity;

      //Each loop adds different data to table
      document.getElementById("PDRTable").innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + num + '</td><td>' + dateFrom + '</td><td>' + dateTo + '</td><td>' + dbActivity + '</td></tr>'

    })
  }
})
```

Im trying to pull data from my Firebase backend and display it in a table, currently it only runs once.

Thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: You have a `return` statement in the `for` loop, so it returns from the function during the first iteration.

Comment: Thank you, didn't even clock that would be the reason. All working now!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on in the dataSnapshot object, but first step in javascript debugging, is to add alert("Here"); in your code to see what (if anything) is being returned

```
//Number of times the loop should run returning a value
    var number = dataSnapshot.val().Total;      

    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < number; i++){
    alert("Here " + i); //Show me the loop variable
    //Each time loop runs changes Firebase reference by "1" 
    return firebase.database().ref('/Users/' + uid + "/PDR/" + i).once('value').then(function display(dataSnapshot) {
    alert(num);
    alert(dateFrom );
    alert(dateTo );
    var num = dataSnapshot.val().number;
    var dateFrom = dataSnapshot.val().dateFrom;
    var dateTo = dataSnapshot.val().dateTo;
    var dbActivity = dataSnapshot.val().activity;                               

    //Each loop adds different data to table
    document.getElementById("PDRTable").innerHTML += '<tr><td>'+ num +'</td><td>'+ dateFrom + '</td><td>'+ dateTo +'</td><td>'+ dbActivity +'</td></tr>'
```

Comment: Of course something is being returned; there's a return statement. (Complicated by the promise stuff.)

Comment: The point is to teach him to fish. If he used the alert debugging method, he should have noticed that once the return is hit, nothing else would be alerted to the browser.

Comment: This isn't an answer though although I do agree with your thought process.